# An Ehrhart positivity question related to Schur polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-functions, lattice-polytopes

Consider the [Schur polynomial](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/schur.htm) $s_\lambda(x_1,\dotsc,x_k)$.
It is easy to see from the hook-content formula for counting the number of semi-standard tableaux, that the function
$$
n \to s_{n \lambda}(1,1,\dotsc,1) = |SSYT(n \lambda,k)|
$$
is a polynomial in $n$ with non-negative coefficients.
Here, $SSYT(\lambda,k)$ denotes the set of semi-standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$, and no entry exceeding $k$. The notation $n\lambda$ denotes element-wise multiplication.

Now, what about the map
$$n \to  s_{n \lambda/n\mu}(1,1,\dotsc,1) = |SSYT(n \lambda/n\mu,k)|$$
where we now consider skew Schur polynomials?

It is easy to prove that this is again a polynomial (it is the Ehrhart polynomial of certain [Gelfand-Tsetlin polytopes](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/gtpatterns.htm#gtpolytopes)), but there is a notorious lack of a hook-content formula for counting skew SSYTs.

**Is there some argument that proves that the above map is a polynomial with *non-negative* coefficients?**

Comment: Would it be  more precise to say "nλ denotes the partition where each part of λ is multiplied by n" instead of "The notation nλ denotes element-wise multiplication"?

Comment: @Wolfgang Sure, that is another way to phrase it.

Comment: To make sure I understand, $k$ is fixed throughout, yes?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Yes, exactly.